# Elegant way to apply series of functions to a string based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a function with x boolean arguments like the following:

```
def generic_function(input_string: str, a = True, b = True, c = True, d = True):
'''A generic function that applies a  series of action
to a string'''

if a == False and b == True and c == True and d == True:

   input_string = action_d(action_c(action_b(input_string)))

else if a == False and b == False and c == True and d == True:

   input_string = action_d(action_c((input_string))

#etc.

return input_string
```

I would like to avoid having to specify each condition specifically and make my code less verbose.

Is there a better, more elegant way to do this? Just to be clear: the original function is part of a class which defines and applies a series of functions to a text to extract some data. For instance, action_a is an emojis removal function, action_b is a tokenizer, etc.

Comment: `a = False` is an assignment, not a comparison. That aside, don't test booleans by comparing with True or False. Simply use `if x: ` or `if not x:`. For example, instead of `if a = False and b = True:` use `if not a and b:`

Comment: @jarmod I have addressed the issue in my latest edit. Thank you, it was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to make every possible combination. Since the logic is to apply a function on the return of the previous one (g∘f), using a sequence of `if` is fine and totally equivalent.

```py
def generic_function(input_string: str, a=True, b=True, c=True, d=True):
    if a:
        input_string = action_a(input_string)
    if b:
        input_string = action_b(input_string)
    if c:
        input_string = action_c(input_string)
    if d:
        input_string = action_d(input_string)
    return input_string
```

Comment: Also including a dictionary/list as `return` to add each resulting string sequentially could be an idea.  Such as
`return = []
if a:
        input_string_a = action_a(input_string)
        return.append(input_string_a)`

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is basically pass an iterable of all the Booleans to `all` builtin which will definitely make your code look cleaner as you have all the conditions combined by `and`, you can use `any` in case if boolean is combined by `or` , or you can combine `all`, `any` depending on the conditions you have.

```py
def generic_function(input_string: str, a = True, b = True, c = True, d = True):
    '''A generic function that applies a  series of action
    to a string'''

    if all((not a,b,c,d,)):
       input_string = action_d(action_c(action_b(input_string)))
    elif all((not a, not b, c, d)):
       input_string = action_d(action_c((input_string))
    #etc.
    
    return input_string
```

Answer (score 1):

we could use some standart libraries and get this quite elegant (IMHO) solution:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import compress

def generic_function(input_string: str, a = True, b = True, c = True, d = True):
    funcs = compress([action_a, action_b, action_c, action_d],[a,b,c,d])
    return reduce(lambda x,y: y(x), funcs, input_string)
```

let's test it:

```
action_a = lambda a: a+'a'
action_b = lambda b: b+'bb'
action_c = lambda c: c+'ccc'
action_d = lambda d: d+'dddd'

generic_function('test_')  # 'test_abbcccdddd'
generic_function('test_', a=False, c=False)  # 'test_bbdddd'
```